# Вывод текста из базы

Tags: php

Есть форма, введя в которую текст, он записывается в базу данных.
Мне нужно сделать вывод этого текста из базы, но чтобы текст выводился с переносом строк, если они есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод сообщения из базы обрабатывайте функцией [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: это получается так `nl2br($post['mess'])` ?

Comment: спасибо! разобрался